# Restricting access to some parts of a site. Google App Engine webapp

Tags: security, google-app-engine

I'm putting user privileges identificator in user sessions after authentication.
How to restrict access to some parts of the site depending on user privileges. For now I'm checking privileges within page handlers but how to make it better?

Are there any existing templates of doing this? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define decorators to make this easier. For example:

```
def requiresUser(fun):
  def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
    if not users.get_current_user():
      self.error(403)
    else:
      fun(*args, **kwargs)
  return decorate

def requiresAdmin(fun):
  def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
    if not users.is_current_user_admin():
      self.error(403)
    else:
      fun(*args, **kwargs)
  return decorate
```

And to use them, just decorate handler methods:

```
class NewsHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  # Only logged in users can read the news
  @requiresUser
  def get(self):
    # Do something

  # Only admins can post news
  @requiresAdmin
  def post(self):
    # Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict certain areas to only admins of your app you can put the following into app.yaml

```
- url: /url.*
  script: path.py
  login: admin
```

otherwise you can check when someone

```
class PathHandler(webapp.RequestHandler): 
  def get(self):
    if users.get_current_user():
       pass #do something
    else:
       self.error(403) #Access denied

 def post(self):
    if users.get_current_user():
       pass #do something
    else:
       self.error(403) #Access denied
```

EDIT: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/oauth/oauth_on_appengine has examples of using OAuth on appengine

Comment: you could use http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/oauth/oauth_on_appengine as a template maybe?